# Why does client connecting to our Windows 2012 R2 Standard OS via VPN, disconnect every 12 hours

Tags: site-to-site-vpn, microsoft

Our server: VM, Win Server 2012 R2 Standard.
Their server: VM, Win Server 2012 Standard.

They open a VPN connection to our external IP
Authenticate using a local account on our host. 
The account is configured to have a static IP.

***Why would the VPN connection get dropped every 12 hours?***
It will stay up for a maximum of 12 hours.
We have a tool that determines whether the connection is open, and if it is down, uses rasdial to open it again... but its sub optimal for the VPN to go down at all.

THe VPN service on our service runs in native windows - we monitor the connection in Routing and Remote Access Version 5.2.0000.0.
The connection is made on WAN Miniport (PPTP) 
It is the only active VPN connection.
Nothing is reported in the event logs.

Any Microsoft network guru people have a clue where to look? Thanks.

Comment: Is the connection active the whole time? What happens if you just start a continuous ping to a remote host and then wait out the 12 hours?

Comment: Not tried this... I have set timeout for sessions that are idle to 99999...